# How to send Get variable from one php file to a next for sql insert

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mysqli

I have website in which each individual user logged in has a session. However if users logged in needs to make a post on someone's page, I need to get that user's username which I have done with this code `if (isset($_GET['u']))`. I can easily submit my form to the database by just processing everything on the same page but I want to avoid page refresh on submit, so I decided to go to the `ajax` route.

Main PHP page:

```
<?php include ( "./inc/incfiles/header.inc.php"); ?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET[ 'u'])) 
{ 
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET[ 'u']); 
  $_SESSION["username_send"] = $username; 
}
?>
<form method="POST" id="myform" name="myform" class="ajaxform" action="<?php echo $username;?>">
  <textarea type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="share your ideas"></textarea>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-idea" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Post</button>
  </div>
</form>
<?php include("inc/incfiles/footer.inc.php"); ?>
```

Now here is the problem, making an ajax call I am running into problems getting `$username` to the `php` processing page. For some reason I am getting a blank entry in my database for `$user_posted_to = "$username"`. This leads me to think that the session created: `$_SESSION["username_send"]`, is not storing the `$_GET['u']` parameter. Is there a better way to send over the variable `$username` in the processing page other than using `$_SESSION`?

PHP process page `send_post.php`:

```
<?php include("./inc/incfiles/connect.inc.php");
session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION["user_log"]))
    {
        $user = ""; 
    }
    else
    {
        $user = $_SESSION["user_log"];
        $username = $_SESSION["username_send"]; 
    }       
?>
<?php   
    $post = strip_tags(@$_POST['name']);
    if ($post !="")
    {
        $date_added = date("Y-m-d");
        $added_by = "$user";
        $user_posted_to = "$username";

        $sql_user_post ="INSERT INTO posts VALUES('','$post','$date_added','$added_by','$user_posted_to')";
        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql_user_post) or die (mysqli_error());
    }
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "send_post.php",
      data: {name:name},
      success: function(){
        alert("It works");
      },
      error:function(e){
        alert("it failed");
      }
    });
  });   
});
```

Comment: Where is your `session_start()` in the Main PHP page?

Comment: you could echo it into a hidden input in your form.  You can serialize the entire form to post it via ajax, or echo it into the data field of your ajax call.  So I guess either echo it into your js or the form, whichever way you prefer to pass it.  I don't think this is a good use of session, because a minute later I might want to comment on another user's page and this value will change within the same session.  It should be page specific

Comment: @JayBlanchard it is in  `include: header.inc.php`.

Comment: @RightClick I was actually thinking about that: echoing it in some hidden field form. I will try that.

Comment: ok, I think that's a good approach. but since you're doing it via ajax, make sure you grab the value like you've done with `name`.  That's why I suggest `serialize()`, because you can leave your js alone and have it submit the entire form, then add fields when you need them without having to edit js

Comment: Hey thanks, I did it already with echo, very efficient. Your other method of using `serialize()`, you would still need to `echo` the username to the form anyway to get the variable.